# Adding Custom Information to SimplePie RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplepie

Hi I am super new to php and rss parsing so please bear with me.

I am trying to take multiple feeds of band tour dates, and put them together, ordered by date, with the band name, date, venue, city, etc. I have accomplished all of this besides adding the band name in. I have tried to figure out how to add custom information from the feed but its confusing the hell out of me.

Here is the feed: http://www.rssmix.com/u/3831476/rss.xml
Here is the page I am working on: http://runforcoverrecords.com/newsite1/newsite.php

It's the Tour Dates section in the bottom right I am referring to. Those are all the bands shows organized correctly, without the band names.

This is what I have:

```
<?php foreach ($feeds->get_items(0, 15) as $item):?>
    <div class="touritem"> 
        <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
              - <?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>
        </a>.  
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code you tried to ensure great answers.

Comment: The feed you're using doesn't appear to have the band name or any article data, just a link to Facebook for each date. Am I missing something?